# Upload multipart image into google cloud storage bucket using postman

Tags: google-cloud-storage

i use this google [reference link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dwn0.png)

I am not getting where and how the base64 image or image data to be passed, can anyone help me using postman

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I understood you're trying to upload an image to Google Cloud Storage through the JSON API, although I can see some inconsistencies on the proces you're following, for example at the step 4 of the documentation it tells you to put content-type set to multipart/related and a boundary string as well as the Content-Length. I would recommend you to re-do the steps described on the link that you send as "[reference link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload)" and also, could you please share a screenshot of the body tab to se what are you doing over there?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but the right way to upload upload an image with postman is this one.

1. Create a token, use this command in your console to get one.
   $gcloud auth print-access-token
2. Add the token in Postman. TokenType: OAuth 2.0
3. Use this link with method POST in Postman
   https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/o?uploadType=media&name=NAME-OF-THE-FILE
4. [The body must be of binary type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPnmI.png)